# Caching images only for PHP application

Tags: caching, nginx, memcached, varnish

I got in my web application (PHP) a feature of uploading and sharing images.
I need to know what is the best caching technology for caching only images.

There will be more reading than writing.

So what do you think the best technology is for my needs?

Is it varnish, memcached or something else?

Comment: why do you want to cache images? Because I/O is too slow? Retrieving an image from disk vs cache is the same except for the difference with I/O, because you are talking about server-side caching.

Comment: I didn't develope this feature yet (I'm just in the planning phase), but as far as I know caching solution is far faster than reading data from disc. doesn't it? and I assume that bottleneck will be created on my server.

Comment: You shouldn't assume, but test. Caching and then serving from memory is faster, but if you can't hold all images in memory and the retrieval of images is random you might not get the speed that you want. Now it doesn't help to think what might be the problem. Develop, then test, then see if you need a caching sollution.

Comment: As stated, caching images is likely to be of no benefit over simply serving them from disc.

Comment: what you're saying is surprising me. 
can you give me the technical explanation?

I know Facebook for example holds hundreds of memcached servers for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you make modifications like watermarking or resizing to the images, then store the modified images as files to disc and let the clients load them directly.

Comment: this will cause a bottleneck..
I need a caching solution

Comment: When the count of request reaches a certain level, every solution on a single machine might become a bottleneck. For really high traffic sites try something like a CDN, maybe AWS S3.